# Quick question about a closed loop control system

Tags: control, control-system, math

[image]

Using above loop, we see that

\$
\dfrac{y(s)}{r(s)} = \dfrac{p(s)c(s)}{1+p(s)c(s)}
\$

and

\$
\dfrac{e(s)}{r(s)} = \dfrac{1}{1+p(s)c(s)}
\$

(well known results)

Why is that:

**If the close loop system is stable, then \$1+p(s)c(s) = 0\$ ?**

Shouldn't it be if the closed loop poles of \$\dfrac{y(s)}{r(s)}\$ are in open left hand plane?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The poles of the TF are the roots of the characteristic equation, \$\small 1+P(s)C(s)=0\$. For a stable system all of these roots must be in the left half s-plane.